# Issue with ng-init in Ionic Select

Tags: select, ionic-framework, ng-init

I am using Ionic Select component for my app built with Ionic and I am stuck at an unusual issue. Below is my code :

```
<select ng-init="quantity = 'item.productQuantity'" ng-model="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

The issue I am facing is that the ng-init doesn't seem to work for me. Here the item.productQuantity defines a single value ranging between 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove '' from `item.productQuantity` in ng-init expression it works:

```
<select ng-init="quantity = item.productQuantity" ng-model="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Here is a Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pIsMmd0HMPYn8WOZYWw5?p=preview